# Selenium TimeOut --> Cannot find the locator

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, input

once again i find myself struggeling with the locator, or lets say the correct way to put it into correct syntax and code.

Here is the Code i was trying to execute:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-xs-6']//input[@class='js-order-amount trading-amount trading-price-field textbox pull-left' and(contains(@data-original-title,'Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?'))]"))).send_keys('33')
```

and here would be the corresponding HTML from the Website:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">

<input class="js-order-amount trading-amount trading-price-field textbox pull-left" type="text" maxlength="9" required="required" placeholder="Menge" value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?">

</div>
```

The Error i get is as follows:

```
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-9c18d6a21146> in <module>
     50 # wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-original-title,'Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?'))]"))).click()
     51 
---> 52 wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-xs-6']//input[@class='js-order-amount trading-amount trading-price-field textbox pull-left' and contains('Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?')]"))).send_keys('33')
     53 
     54 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

i thought, especially the part of

```
@data-original-title,'Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?'
```

is unice to this text/input Field. But how can i use this as a valid locator?

Or maybe the input field is somewhat "hidden" in other divs?

would appreciate some hints or help, thanks a lot,

Benjamim

Comment: I guess this element is still on the site/page we talked about yesterday? If so  - where this element is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the below xpath with `@data-original-title,'Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?'`

```
//input[@data-container='body'][@data-original-title='Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?']
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Update 1 :**

Based on the new error reported by **OP**, it may be solved via below ways

1. Use **Actions Chain:**

   ```
   time.sleep(5)
   button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-container='body'][@data-original-title='Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?']")
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).send_keys('33').perform()
   ```
2. **Use JS :**

   ```
   time.sleep(5)
   button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-container='body'][@data-original-title='Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?']")
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button)
   button.send_keys('33')
   ```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: okay, that seem to work, the locator is unique and selenium finds it. However now i get the Error Message: ElementNotInteractableException

Comment: @BenjaminDiLorenzo :  See above the updated code. Also we do not encourage to ask multiple follow up questions in comment section, Please always create a new ticket for new error/issues.

Comment: okay thank you for that suggestion. I also searched for the "move_to_element" execution that might work for that caseö. Unfortunately i now get the Error:  ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLInputElement] has no size and location
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82) --> i guess that means i have to define a location and size?

Comment: The above error which you have reported here, is basically element couldn't rendered properly, please put some delay before accessing the element

Comment: okay, i added a delay of 20 seconds before the action.chain executes, its still giving me this error. I will post a new Question with that Error i guess. Also i was curious, why did you choose to inlcude the "style='block' part as a locator? is this important to locate the element?

Comment: Are you sure you are replying on the correct thread ? I have not used `"style='block' ` at all in any of my locator

Comment: right, sorry. That was the wrong line. You used @data-container='body' . Did you use this because it seemed unique to the input field? unfortunately, the locator is correct (in chrome it points only to that input field) but while i execute the code, Selenium still wont find it. It says: no size or location. Still with the action chain

Comment: yes I chose that cause that was unique. Where exactly is this element located ? I mean do you have to manually scroll up or down to see this element ?

Comment: no it is exactly in the middle and within the viewport. Thats why it is confusing to me, that this Error occurs.

Comment: I would have to have the page url with creds to investigate more into this issue.

Comment: alright, can i send it to you via chat? or contact?

Comment: Yes you can, if you have the code written to login and stuff do share as well, otterwise I'll have to write it from scratch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237350/discussion-between-benjamindilorenzo-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: hello cruisepandey, i send the login via chat to you

Comment: after login what are the steps  ?

Comment: well, if you run the script, you will see the Error Message (eithe the Element is not interactable or it times out) and also can check the HTML from the page directly. I also opened a new threat for this, because it seemed to me, that this issue cannot be solved by the answers that are allready provided in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295694/selenium-correct-locator-but-cannot-interact-with-the-element-input-field