# Selenium: Correct locator but cannot interact with the element (input-field)

Tags: python, html, selenium, dom, xpath

I try to interact with an input field with the following script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep


username = "****"
password = "****"

url = "https://www.wikifolio.com/dynamic/de/de/login/login?ReturnUrl=/de/de/home&_=1632037782306"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'\Users\Benjamin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_name("Username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("Password").send_keys(password)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button").click()

driver.get("https://www.wikifolio.com/de/de/meine-wikifolios/trade/wf00wiking")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__abort, .c-disclaimer .js-disclaimer__change"))).click()


wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-description='AKER CARB.CAPT.AS NK1']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='trading-modal-root' and(contains(@style,'block'))]//select[@class='js-order-type-select order-type-selector']")))
select1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='trading-modal-root' and(contains(@style,'block'))]//select[@class='js-order-type-select order-type-selector']"))


select1.select_by_value('quote')


#to select purchase or sale action:
select2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='trading-modal-root' and(contains(@style,'block'))]//select[@class='js-order-type-buysell order-buysell-selector']"))

# select by value "buy"
select2.select_by_value('buy')




buttonnew = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/input")))

newaction = ActionChains(driver)
newaction.move_to_element(buttonnew).send_keys(int(22)).perform()
```

The Script executes correct unless it comes to the last part:

```
buttonnew = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/input")))

newaction = ActionChains(driver)
newaction.move_to_element(buttonnew).send_keys(int(22)).perform()
```

Here the execution stops.

I checked the XPATH with the browser. It is unique. I checked with Chrome via "examine" and then pressing >CRTL + F<

Here is a screenshot, that Chrome DOES indeed find the locator and it seems to be unique:
[image: XAPTH from the Browser Viewport]

That seems to indicate, that the XPATH is correct, and it is not a matter of "finding" the right XPATH but rather a matter of code execution or wrong programming.

Also i was wondering, if the Input Field is wrapped inside a Shadow DOM or any other form of hidden structure.

But if this was the case, why all the other field CAN be selected (like selecting from the dropdown) in the previous steps?

To let you check that correctly i would provide the full html of that panel (because it is a window that opens within that page):

```
<div>
            <div id="trade-dialog-container">
    <div id="trading-modal-root" role="dialog" class="modal fade publish trading-modal-root in" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="authorization-request-panel" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="spinner-modal-wrapper">
                        <div class="spinner"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="trading-panel clearfix" style="">
                    <div class="trading-panel-close modal-close-button" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <i class="icon-close4"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-push-6 trading-panel-preview-col trade-panel-col">
                        <div class="trading-panel-preview">
                            <div class="trading-panel-preview-wrapper">
                                <div id="trade-main-modal-header" class="trading-panel-header">
            <h4 class="trade-popup-title-shortdesc">AKER CARB.CAPT.AS NK1</h4>
            <span class="trade-popup-title-sub">
                <span id="js-underlying-isin" data-issuer="1900">
                    NO0010890304 (L&amp;S Kurse)
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
                                <div class="row trading-panel-price-container">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 trading-panel-price-wrapper">
                                        <div class="trading-panel-price">
                                            <div class="currentBid text-center">2,392<small>EUR</small></div>
                                            <span class="trading-panel-price-sub">Verkaufskurs (Bid)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 trading-panel-price-wrapper">
                                        <div class="trading-panel-price">
                                            <div class="currentAsk text-center">2,423<small>EUR</small></div>
                                            <span class="trading-panel-price-sub">Kaufkurs (Ask)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="trading-panel-summary">
                                    <table class="trading-summary-panel">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr class="js-switch-nobuysell-row" style="display: none;">
                                                <td colspan="2">Bestand (aktuell)</td>
                                                <td class="text-bold text-right">
                                                    <span class="js-amount-underlying">14.477</span>&nbsp;Stk.
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr style="" class="js-switch-buysell-row">
                                                <td>Bestand</td>
                                                <td class="text-right trading-prev-value">
                                                    <span class="js-amount-underlying">14.477</span>&nbsp;Stk.
                                                    <i class="icon-right"></i>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-bold text-right js-hideable-cell" style="visibility: visible;">
                                                    <span class="js-trade-amount-sum">14.478</span>&nbsp;Stk.
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="js-switch-nobuysell-row" style="display: none;">
                                                <td colspan="2">Cash (aktuell)</td>
                                                <td class="text-bold text-right">
                                                    <span data-value="264258.715" class="trade-popup-wikifolio-cash">264.258,715</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr style="" class="js-switch-buysell-row">
                                                <td>Cash</td>
                                                <td class="text-right trading-prev-value">
                                                    <span data-value="264258.715" class="trade-popup-wikifolio-cash">264.258,715</span>
                                                    <i class="icon-right"></i>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="text-bold text-right js-hideable-cell" style="visibility: visible;">
                                                    <span data-value="264258.715" class="trade-popup-cash-after-trade" data-cash="264256.292">264.256,292</span>&nbsp;*
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">Orderwert</td>
                                                <td class="text-bold text-right js-hideable-cell" style="visibility: visible;">
                                                    <span class="js-order-value">2,423</span><span class="js-order-value-hidden" style="display: none;">&nbsp;*</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" row trading-panel-notice hidden-xs">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        Alle Preise in EUR
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                                        * abhängig vom Ausführungspreis
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="trading-panel-message-container hidden-xs">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-pull-6 col-lg-pull-6 trading-panel-detail-col trade-panel-col">
                        <div class="trading-panel-settings">
                            <div class="trading-panel-settings-wrapper">
                                <div class="row u-mb-3">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select js-order-type-select order-type-selector bs3" style="width: 100%;"><select class="js-order-type-select order-type-selector" style="opacity: 0" data-width="100%">
                                            <option value="quote" selected="selected">Quote</option>
                                            <option value="limit">Limit</option>
                                                <option value="stop">Stop-Limit</option>
                                        </select><button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="combobox" aria-owns="bs-select-5" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" title="Quote"><div class="filter-option"><div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Quote</div></div> </div><span class="bs-caret"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="5" viewBox="0 0 8 5"><polyline fill="none" stroke="#BBC4C7" stroke-width="1.5" points="2.5 -.5 5.5 2.5 2.5 5.5" transform="rotate(90 4 2.5)"></polyline></svg></span></button><div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 592px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px;"><div class="inner open" role="listbox" id="bs-select-5" tabindex="-1" aria-activedescendant="bs-select-5-0" style="max-height: 592px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;"><ul class="dropdown-menu inner " role="presentation" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><li class="selected active"><a role="option" class="dropdown-item active selected" id="bs-select-5-0" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="1" aria-selected="true"><span class="text">Quote</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-1" tabindex="0"><span class="text">Limit</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-5-2" tabindex="0"><span class="text">Stop-Limit</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select js-order-type-buysell order-buysell-selector bs3" style="width: 100%;"><select class="js-order-type-buysell order-buysell-selector" style="opacity: 0" data-width="100%" tabindex="null">
                                            <option selected="selected">Bitte wählen...</option>
                                            <option value="buy">Kauf</option>
                                            <option value="sell">Verkauf</option>
                                        </select><button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="combobox" aria-owns="bs-select-4" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" title="Kauf"><div class="filter-option"><div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Kauf</div></div> </div><span class="bs-caret"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="5" viewBox="0 0 8 5"><polyline fill="none" stroke="#BBC4C7" stroke-width="1.5" points="2.5 -.5 5.5 2.5 2.5 5.5" transform="rotate(90 4 2.5)"></polyline></svg></span></button><div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 592px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px;"><div class="inner open" role="listbox" id="bs-select-4" tabindex="-1" aria-activedescendant="bs-select-4-1" style="max-height: 592px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;"><ul class="dropdown-menu inner " role="presentation" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-4-0" tabindex="0"><span class="text">Bitte wählen...</span></a></li><li class="selected active"><a role="option" class="dropdown-item active selected" id="bs-select-4-1" tabindex="0" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="2" aria-selected="true"><span class="text">Kauf</span></a></li><li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-4-2" tabindex="0"><span class="text">Verkauf</span></a></li></ul></div></div></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <span class="settings-label">Stück</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <input class="js-order-amount trading-amount trading-price-field textbox pull-left" type="text" maxlength="9" required="required" placeholder="Menge" value="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Wie viele Stück möchten Sie kaufen?">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row js-stop-order-row" style="display: none">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <span class="settings-label"><span class="trade-popup-stop-price-text">Stop-Limit</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <input class="js-trade-popup-stop-price js-trading-decimal-field trading-price-field textbox" maxlength="15" type="text" value="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="<div class=' wikifolio-tooltip-icon'></div>
                <div class='wikifolio-tooltip-text'>***</div>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row js-limit-or-stop-order-row" style="display: none">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <span class="settings-label">Limit</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <input class="js-trade-popup-limit-price js-trading-decimal-field trading-price-field textbox" type="text" maxlength="15" value="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="<div class=' wikifolio-tooltip-icon'></div>
                <div class='wikifolio-tooltip-text'>***</div>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row js-limit-or-stop-order-row" style="display: none">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <span class="settings-label limit-trade-valid-until-text hidden-xs">Gültig bis (Tagesende)</span>
                                        <span class="settings-label limit-trade-valid-until-text hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Gültig bis</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="js-datepicker-valid-until">
                                            <span class="textbox-icon-left textbox-icon-clickable js-valid-until-icon">
                                                <i class="icon-calendar2"></i>
                                            </span>
                                            <input class="limit-order-valid-until-date js-limit-order-valid-until textbox" type="text" maxlength="10" value="23.10.2021" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="<div class=' wikifolio-tooltip-icon'></div>
                <div class='wikifolio-tooltip-text'>Ihre Order läuft zum gewählten Tag, um 23:59 Uhr automatisch ab.</div>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="trade-popup-tpsl-xs-border u-mt-3" style="display: none">
                                        <div class="row js-trade-popup-tp-row" style="display: none">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="trading-dialog-tpsl-row checkbox" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="<div class=' wikifolio-tooltip-icon'></div>
                <div class='wikifolio-tooltip-text'>***</div>">
                                                    <input id="modal-dialog-take-profit-checkbox" type="checkbox" class="trade-popup-take-profit-checkbox">
                                                    <label for="modal-dialog-take-profit-checkbox" class="trading-dialog-take-profit-label">Take Profit platzieren</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="js-trade-popup-cell-tp-active js-trade-popup-cell-tp-deleted-container" style="display: none">
                                            <div class="row js-trade-popup-tp-row" style="display: none;">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                    <span class="settings-label">
                                                        <span class="js-trade-popup-cell-tp-active" style="display: none;">
                                                            <span class="limit-trade-amount-sum-text">Limit</span>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span class="trade-popup-cell-tp-inactive js-trade-popup-cell-tp-deleted" style="display: none;"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 js-trade-popup-cell-tp-active" style="display: none;">
                                                    <input class="inline js-take-profit-limit-price js-trading-decimal-field trading-price-field textbox" maxlength="15" type="text" value="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="<div class=' wikifolio-tooltip-icon'></div>
                <div class='wikifolio-tooltip-text'>Z***</div>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="trade-popup-tpsl-xs-border u-mt-2" style="display: none;">
                                        <div class="row js-trade-popup-sl-row js-trade-popup-sl-row-first" style="display: none">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="trading-dialog-tpsl-row checkbox" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="<div class=' wikifolio-tooltip-icon'></div>
                <div class='wikifolio-tooltip-text'>***</div>">
                                                    <input id="modal-dialog-stop-loss-checkbox" type="checkbox" class="trade-popup-stop-loss-checkbox">
                                                    <label for="modal-dialog-stop-loss-checkbox" class="trading-dialog-stop-loss-label">Stop-Loss platzieren</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="js-trade-popup-cell-sl-active js-trade-popup-cell-sl-deleted-container" style="display: none">
                                            <div class="row js-trade-popup-sl-row trade-popup-sl-row js-trade-popup-sl-row-first" style="display: none;">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                    <span class="settings-label">
                                                        <span style="display: none;" class="js-trade-popup-cell-sl-active">Stop-Limit</span>
                                                        <span class="js-trade-popup-cell-sl-inactive js-trade-popup-cell-sl-deleted" style="display: none;"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 js-trade-popup-cell-sl-active" style="display: none;">
                                                    <input class="inline js-trade-popup-sl-stop-price js-trading-decimal-field trading-price-field textbox" maxlength="15" type="text" value="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="<div class=' wikifolio-tooltip-icon'></div>
                <div class='wikifolio-tooltip-text'>***</div>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row js-trade-popup-row-sl-active js-trade-popup-sl-row js-trade-popup-sl-row-second" style="display: none;">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                    <span class="settings-label">
                                                        <span style="display: none;" class="js-trade-popup-cell-sl-active">Limit</span>
                                                        <span class="js-trade-popup-cell-sl-inactive"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 js-trade-popup-cell-sl-active" style="display: none;">
                                                    <input class="inline js-trade-popup-sl-limit-price js-trading-decimal-field trading-price-field textbox" maxlength="15" type="text" value="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-container="body" data-placement="right" title="<div class=' wikifolio-tooltip-icon'></div>
                <div class='wikifolio-tooltip-text'>***</div>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="trading-panel-notice trading-panel-notice-tutorial js-tutorial-row text-center visible-xs" style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="js-limit-order-tutorial-row" style="display: none;">
                                       ***
                                        <br>
                                        ***
                                        <a class="area capitalized" href="/de/de/hilfe/tutorials-trader/limit-orders" target="_blank"><span>mehr...</span></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="js-stop-limit-order-tutorial-row" style="display: none;">
                                       ***
                                        <br>
                                        ***
                                        <a class="area capitalized" href="/de/de/hilfe/tutorials-trader/stop-limit-orders" target="_blank"><span>mehr...</span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

.......
```

Now the question: do i need to adress one of the parent or ancestor elements (divs for example) BEFORE i can interact with the input field?

Also i was wondering what this part in the HTML is about:

```
<div class="authorization-request-panel" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="spinner-modal-wrapper">
                        <div class="spinner"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is written directly after the "modal-dialog" div in the HTML.

I also checked multiple threats here in Stackoverflow. All of the solutions lead to an incorecct XPATH Locator. But why the XPATH then uniquely points to the correct input field, when i insert this into the browser directly, like it is in the screenshot?

Can anyone help me with that issue?

Thanks a lot, i appreciate,
Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Xpath is brittle in nature, try to use **relative xpath** rather than **absolute xpath**.
2. Make sure to use `element_to_be_clickable`  when it is required.
3. You need to clear the input field first and then you can do `send_keys`
4. Use `explicit waits`.
5. Launch browser in full screen mode.
6. Preference is `css selector`, and least preferable choice is **xpath**.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
#driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.wikifolio.com/dynamic/de/de/login/login?ReturnUrl=/de/de/home&_=1632037782306")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "Username"))).send_keys('******')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Password"))).send_keys('******')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.gtm-login"))).click()

driver.get("https://www.wikifolio.com/de/de/meine-wikifolios/trade/wf00wiking")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.js-disclaimer__change"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-description='AKER CARB.CAPT.AS NK1']"))).click()
select1  = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.dropdown>select.order-type-selector"))
select1.select_by_value('quote')

#to select purchase or sale action:
select2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.dropdown>select.order-buysell-selector"))
# select by value "buy"
select2.select_by_value('buy')

buttonnew = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[contains(@class,'trading-amount')])[2]")))
buttonnew.clear()
buttonnew.send_keys("22")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't necessary to address one of the parent or ancestor elements before interacting with the input field (unless the element is inside a frame of frame-set). Could you please pass "22" as a string and not an integer?

```
# passing "22" as a string
newaction.move_to_element(buttonnew).send_keys(str(22)).perform()
```